# Ambient Isotopic subsets but not their embeddings

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I am trying to find two embeddings $f$ and $g$ of the circle $S^{1}$ into a space $X$ such that the subsets $f(S^{1})$ and $g(S^{1})$ are ambient isotopic within $X$, but $f$
and $g$ are not ambient isotopic within $X$.

This is problem 10 in "An Illustrated Introduction to Topology and Homotopy", by Sasho Kalajdzievski - page 226. It is before the material on homotopy and the fundamental group. Hence, I assume none of that is needed to provide the answer.

Comment: Just embed circle into circle by two maps with opposite orientation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Then as per your suggestion $X=S^{1}$, $f$ the identity and $g$ the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$ would work. Or $X=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $f$ the inclusion, with $g$ as before.

Comment: Right..........

Comment: Sorry, I can see why they are ambient isotopic as subsets (the identity isotopy works), but I cannot see why there is no continuous map $H:S^{1}\times I\rightarrow S^{1}$ such that all $H_{t}$ are homeomorphisms, and $H_{0}=\mathrm{id}$ while $H_{1}=g$ (as $H_{1}\circ f=H_{1}$ since $f$ is just the identity)

Comment: The are not even freely homotopic, think about the fundamental group or 1st homology.

Comment: Ok, there has to be another way of answering my question then. The question is before the material on homotopy an the fundamental group.

Comment: What's the source?

Comment: I added it in the question above

Comment: One can also prove non-existence of isotope using the intermediate value theorem, but it is a bit ugly.

Comment: Regarding your assertion that "there has to be another way", I would imagine the author of that book would be perfectly happy if some person reading their book stumbled across this circle example and then decided to learn the theory of the fundamental group just for the purpose of justifying the example. @John

Comment: No doubt about that :) Onwards I go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the question from the unanswered list I try providing a solution using the Intermediate Value Theorem. This solution was suggested to me by Dr. Sasho Kalajdzievski.

Consider the inclusion $i:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ and $g:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ defined by $g(x,y)=(x,-y)$.

Suppose $H:S^{1}\times I\rightarrow S^{1}$ is a continuous mapping such that the mappings $H_{t}:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$, defined by $H_{1}(x)=H(x,t)$ for $t\in I$ satisfy $H_{0}=\mathrm{id}_{S^{1}}$ and $H_{1}=g$.

Now, for a point $p\in S^{1}$ different from $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ consider the "vertical line" $X=\{x\}\times I$ and the map $h:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(t)$ as the magnitude in radians of the central angle from $H_{t}(p)$ to $H_{t}(1,0)$ (this magnitude is positive if the central angle is clockwise and negative if it is anticlockwise).

Note that this magnitude depends continuously on $H$, which is continuous. Therefore, $h$ is continuous. Moreover, $h(0)$ is positive (res. negative) if and only if $h(1)$ is negative (resp. postive). Therefore, $h$ changes sign on $I$ and by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is some $c\in I$ for which $h(c)=0$. But then, $H_{c}(p)=H_{c}(1,0)$ implying that $H_{c}$ is not injective. Therefore, $H$ cannot be an ambient isotopy between $i$ and $g$ within $S^{1}$.

On the other hand, $i(S^{1})$ and$f(S^{1})$ are clearly isotopic subsets since they are both equal to $S^{1}$.