# Equivalent embeddings vs equivalent subsets

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Two embeddings $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are equivalent if there is a homeomorphism $h:Y\rightarrow Y$ such that $h\circ f=g$.

Two subsets $A,B$ of $Y$ are equivalent if there is a homeomorphism $h:Y\rightarrow Y$ such that $h(A)=B$.

Clearly, if $f$ and $g$ are equivalent embeddings then the subsets $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are equivalent. However, is the converse always true? That is, if $f$ and $g$ are embeddings such that $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are equivalent, does it follow that $f$ and $g$ are equivalent embeddings?

Edit: Ambient isotopic embeddings are equivalent embeddings (although the reverse implication is not true. The trefoil knot embedding of $S^{1}$ in $3$-space and its mirror image are equivalent embeddings, but not ambient isotopic). However, the analog converse of the statement above for ambient isotopic subsets is not true. See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627226/ambient-isotopic-subsets-but-not-their-embeddings?noredirect=1#comment9761072_4627226).

Comment: Think about maps of finite sets to the real line.

Comment: And in case you want connected examples: maps from $[0,1]$ to itself can have *equal* images but be non equivalent.

Comment: Ok thank you! Will think about those suggestions. Perhaps you know the answer to this more theory oriented question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627144/when-is-being-ambient-isotopic-for-embeddings-and-for-subsets-an-equivalence-r

Comment: @MorA. would you please give an example? I do not see how two embeddings of $[0,1]$ can have equal images but be non-equivalent

Comment: The point is that the maps $f$ and $g$ need not be homeomorphisms! For a concrete example take $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1-x}{2}$ (with $X=Y=[0,1]$)

Comment: I see, if I am not mistaken then any map $h:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $h\circ f=g$ would have to be $h(x)=-x+\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and thus either cannot be continuous at $x=1/2$ or it fails to be injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to take this question off the unanswered list. Consider $Y={\mathbb R}$ with the standard topology and $X=\{0, 1, 2\}\subset Y$ with the subspace (discrete) topology. Take $f$ to be the identity embedding. Define $g: X\to Y$ by $g(0)=0, g(1)=2, g(2)=1$. Then, of course, $f(X)=g(X)$ are equivalent subsets, but $f$ is not equivalent to $g$.